# How to output data from Structure to CSV using StringBuilder

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder, records

I have data in the following structure:

```
Structure student
    Dim stdntpass As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim sname As String
    Dim age As Byte
    Dim year As Integer
    Dim stdntuser As String
End Structure
```

I need to take the data in that structure and output it to CSV.  I was planning on using a `StringBuilder` object to do it, but I can't figure out how to give the structure to the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "record structure".  Do you mean using a `StringBuilder` to build a SQL command?  Or are you talking about a fixed-width string structure?

Comment: String builders for csv file, and no, they're not fixed length. And you know the 'Structure' command.

Comment: By "Structure command", are you referring to the `Structure` keyword in VB.NET which is used for defining value types (as opposed to `Class` for reference types)?

Comment: So, you're asking, how do you take the data in that `Structure` and output it to a CSV string using a `StringBuilder` object?

Comment: Yes. I'm terrible at explaining...

Comment: That's OK.  I've edited your question to make it more clear.  Let me know if I misstated your situation in any way.  I will now request that this question is re-opened.  If it doesn't get reopened, I would recommend re-asking your question using my edited version.  You should get much better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that uses reflection to determine what fields exist in the `student` structure:

```
Public Function StudentsToCSV(students As IEnumerable(Of student)) As String
    Const separator As Char = ";"c
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    'Get the data elements
    Dim studentFields = GetType(student).GetFields()

    'Output headline (may be removed)
    For Each field In studentFields
        sb.Append(field.Name)
        sb.Append(separator)
    Next
    sb.AppendLine("")

    'Write a line for each student
    For Each s In students
        'Write the value of each field
        For Each field In studentFields
            Dim value As String = Convert.ToString(field.GetValue(s))
            sb.Append(value)
            '... followed by the separator
            sb.Append(separator)
        Next
        sb.AppendLine("")
    Next
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

You can pass any set of `students` to this function - may it be an array, a `List(Of student)` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The `StringBuilder` has no way to take a whole `Structure` and automatically append each of the properties from that `Structure`.  If you must use a `StringBuilder`, you could do it like this:

```
builder.Append(s.stdntpass)
builder.Append(",")
builder.Append(s.fname)
builder.Append(",")
builder.Append(s.sname)
builder.Append(",")
builder.Append(s.age)
builder.Append(",")
builder.Append(s.year)
builder.Append(",")
builder.Append(s.stdntuser)
Dim csvLine As String = builder.ToString()
```

However, it would be easier to use the `String.Join` method, like this:

```
Dim csvLine As String = String.Join(",", s.stdntpass, s.fname, s.sname, s.age, s.year, s.stdntuser)
```

You could use `reflection` to dynamically get the list of properties from the structure, but then you won't have much control over the order in which the fields get appended without using attributes, or something, which could get ugly.

In any case, you should be careful, though, that values are properly escaped.  If any of the strings in your structure contain commas, you need to surround that field with quotation marks.  And if any of those strings quotation marks, they need to be doubled.  You could fix the values with a method like this:

```
Public Function EscapeValueForCsv(value As String) As String
    Return """" & value.Replace("""", """""") & """"
End Function
```

Then you could call that on each of the properties before passing it to `String.Join`:

```
Dim csvLine As String = String.Join _
    (
    ",", 
    EscapeValueForCsv(s.stdntpass), 
    EscapeValueForCsv(s.fname), 
    EscapeValueForCsv(s.sname), 
    EscapeValueForCsv(s.age.ToString()),
    EscapeValueForCsv(s.year.ToString()), 
    EscapeValueForCsv(s.stdntuser)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to override the ToString function.  now passing a whole object to a stringbuilder or even sending the Tostring function to the file will pass the values how you want them:

```
Structure student
    Dim stdntpass As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim sname As String
    Dim age As Byte
    Dim year As Integer
    Dim stdntuser As String
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Join({stdntpass, fname, sname, age.ToString, year.ToString, stdntuser}, ","c) + vbNewLine
    End Function
End Structure
```